# Unable to deploy spring boot application in tomcat

Tags: java, spring-boot, tomcat

When I run the spring boot application in the embedded server of Eclipse it works fine.
But when i deploy the application i have an error when the application try to start.
**I'm using java 17, spring boot 2.6.1 and tomcat 9.0.58**

this is my pom.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0" xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance" xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/xsd/maven-4.0.0.xsd">
    <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>

    <groupId>aa</groupId>
    <artifactId>MM</artifactId>
    <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
    <name>MM</name>
    <description>RP</description>
    <packaging>war</packaging>
    <parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.1</version>
        <relativePath />
    </parent>

    <properties>
        <project.build.sourceEncoding>UTF-8</project.build.sourceEncoding>
        <project.reporting.outputEncoding>UTF-8</project.reporting.outputEncoding>
        <java.version>17</java.version>
    </properties>
    <dependencies>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-devtools</artifactId>
            <optional>true</optional>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-data-jpa</artifactId>
            <exclusions>
                <exclusion>
                    <groupId>org.slf4j</groupId>
                    <artifactId>slf4j-api</artifactId>
                </exclusion>
            </exclusions>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-jdbc</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-web</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.postgresql</groupId>
            <artifactId>postgresql</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>javax.validation</groupId>
            <artifactId>validation-api</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-test</artifactId>
            <scope>test</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-security</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
            <artifactId>hibernate-core</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.modelmapper</groupId>
            <artifactId>modelmapper</artifactId>
            <version>2.3.5</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.projectlombok</groupId>
            <artifactId>lombok</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.commons</groupId>
            <artifactId>commons-collections4</artifactId>
            <version>4.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.security</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-security-jwt</artifactId>
            <version>1.1.0.RELEASE</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>io.jsonwebtoken</groupId>
            <artifactId>jjwt</artifactId>
            <version>0.9.1</version>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-mail</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-thymeleaf</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
            <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springdoc</groupId>
            <artifactId>springdoc-openapi-ui</artifactId>
            <version>1.5.13</version>
        </dependency>
     
    </dependencies>
    <build>
        <plugins>

            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-compiler-plugin</artifactId>
                <configuration>
                    <annotationProcessorPaths>
                        <annotationProcessorPath>
                            <groupId>org.hibernate</groupId>
                            <artifactId>hibernate-jpamodelgen</artifactId>
                            <version>5.6.5.Final</version>
                        </annotationProcessorPath>
                    </annotationProcessorPaths>
                  <finalName>mm</finalName>
                </configuration>
            </plugin>
         
            <plugin>
                <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
                <artifactId>spring-boot-maven-plugin</artifactId>
            </plugin>
         
        </plugins>
    </build>

</project>
```

and this is the error log

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2022-03-03 21:57:55.692  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] MMRR.MMApplication       : Starting MMApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.1 on localhost with PID 34473 (/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/Mo>
2022-03-03 21:57:55.747  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] MMRR.MMApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-03 21:58:15.356  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-03 21:58:23.185  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 7595 ms. Found 25 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-03 21:58:36.080  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 39841 ms
2022-03-03 21:58:52.510  WARN 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependen>
2022-03-03 21:58:52.746  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-03 21:58:53.439 ERROR 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-42] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field brandDao in MMRR.contoroller.BrandController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

03-Mar-2022 21:58:53.482 SEVERE [http-nio-8080-exec-42] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Error deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/MM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
        java.lang.IllegalStateException: Error starting child
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:729)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChild(ContainerBase.java:698)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHost.addChild(StandardHost.java:696)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR(HostConfig.java:1024)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployApps(HostConfig.java:544)
                at org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.check(HostConfig.java:1690)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:77)
                at java.base/jdk.internal.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:43)
                at java.base/java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:568)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.modeler.BaseModelMBean.invoke(BaseModelMBean.java:293)
                at java.management/com.sun.jmx.interceptor.DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.invoke(DefaultMBeanServerInterceptor.java:814)
                at java.management/com.sun.jmx.mbeanserver.JmxMBeanServer.invoke(JmxMBeanServer.java:802)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.ManagerServlet.check(ManagerServlet.java:1614)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.upload(HTMLManagerServlet.java:292)
                at org.apache.catalina.manager.HTMLManagerServlet.doPost(HTMLManagerServlet.java:210)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:681)
                at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:764)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:227)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.CsrfPreventionFilter.doFilter(CsrfPreventionFilter.java:211)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
      at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
                at org.apache.tomcat.websocket.server.WsFilter.doFilter(WsFilter.java:53)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
                at org.apache.catalina.filters.HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.doFilter(HttpHeaderSecurityFilter.java:126)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:189)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:162)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:197)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:97)
                at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:659)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:135)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:92)
                at org.apache.catalina.valves.AbstractAccessLogValve.invoke(AbstractAccessLogValve.java:687)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:78)
                at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:359)
                at org.apache.coyote.http11.Http11Processor.service(Http11Processor.java:399)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProcessorLight.process(AbstractProcessorLight.java:65)
                at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$ConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:889)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.NioEndpoint$SocketProcessor.doRun(NioEndpoint.java:1735)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.SocketProcessorBase.run(SocketProcessorBase.java:49)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1191)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:659)
                at org.apache.tomcat.util.threads.TaskThread$WrappingRunnable.run(TaskThread.java:61)
                at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:833)
        Caused by: org.apache.catalina.LifecycleException: Failed to start component [StandardEngine[Catalina].StandardHost[localhost].StandardContext[/MM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]]
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.handleSubClassException(LifecycleBase.java:440)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:198)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.ContainerBase.addChildInternal(ContainerBase.java:726)
                ... 45 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependencyException: Error creating bean with name 'brandController': Unsatisfied dependency expressed through field 'brandDao'; nested exception is org.springframework.bea>
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:659)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.inject(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:639)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.InjectionMetadata.inject(InjectionMetadata.java:119)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.postProcessProperties(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:399)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1431)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.preInstantiateSingletons(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:944)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.finishBeanFactoryInitialization(AbstractApplicationContext.java:918)
                at org.springframework.context.support.AbstractApplicationContext.refresh(AbstractApplicationContext.java:583)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.context.ServletWebServerApplicationContext.refresh(ServletWebServerApplicationContext.java:145)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refresh(SpringApplication.java:730)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.refreshContext(SpringApplication.java:412)
                at org.springframework.boot.SpringApplication.run(SpringApplication.java:302)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.run(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:175)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.createRootApplicationContext(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:155)
                at org.springframework.boot.web.servlet.support.SpringBootServletInitializer.onStartup(SpringBootServletInitializer.java:97)
                at org.springframework.web.SpringServletContainerInitializer.onStartup(SpringServletContainerInitializer.java:174)
                at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContext.startInternal(StandardContext.java:5219)
                at org.apache.catalina.util.LifecycleBase.start(LifecycleBase.java:183)
                ... 46 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name 'brandDao' defined in MMRR.repository.BrandDao defined in @EnableJpaRepositories declared on JpaRepositoriesRegistrar.En>
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:389)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:134)
         at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.applyPropertyValues(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1707)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.populateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1452)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:619)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.lambda$doGetBean$0(AbstractBeanFactory.java:335)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.getSingleton(DefaultSingletonBeanRegistry.java:234)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:333)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.config.DependencyDescriptor.resolveCandidate(DependencyDescriptor.java:276)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.doResolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1380)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.resolveDependency(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:1300)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor$AutowiredFieldElement.resolveFieldValue(AutowiredAnnotationBeanPostProcessor.java:656)
                ... 69 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.BeanCreationException: Error creating bean with name '(inner bean)#25c54ad': Cannot resolve reference to bean 'entityManagerFactory' while setting constructor argument; nested excepti>
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:342)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveValueIfNecessary(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:113)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.resolveConstructorArguments(ConstructorResolver.java:693)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.ConstructorResolver.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(ConstructorResolver.java:510)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.instantiateUsingFactoryMethod(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1352)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBeanInstance(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:1195)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.doCreateBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:582)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.createBean(AbstractAutowireCapableBeanFactory.java:542)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveInnerBean(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:374)
                ... 82 more
        Caused by: org.springframework.beans.factory.NoSuchBeanDefinitionException: No bean named 'entityManagerFactory' available
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.DefaultListableBeanFactory.getBeanDefinition(DefaultListableBeanFactory.java:863)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getMergedLocalBeanDefinition(AbstractBeanFactory.java:1344)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.doGetBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:309)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.AbstractBeanFactory.getBean(AbstractBeanFactory.java:208)
                at org.springframework.beans.factory.support.BeanDefinitionValueResolver.resolveReference(BeanDefinitionValueResolver.java:330)
                ... 90 more
03-Mar-2022 21:58:53.613 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-42] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deployment of web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/MM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war] has finished in [254,495>
03-Mar-2022 22:08:09.570 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-51] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were >
```

```
 :: Spring Boot ::                (v2.6.1)

2022-03-03 22:08:45.596  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] MMRR.MMApplication       : Starting MMApplication v0.0.1-SNAPSHOT using Java 17.0.1 on localhost with PID 34473 (/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/Mo>
2022-03-03 22:08:45.625  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] MMRR.MMApplication       : No active profile set, falling back to default profiles: default
2022-03-03 22:09:05.899  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Bootstrapping Spring Data JPA repositories in DEFAULT mode.
2022-03-03 22:09:09.437  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] .s.d.r.c.RepositoryConfigurationDelegate : Finished Spring Data repository scanning in 3257 ms. Found 25 JPA repository interfaces.
2022-03-03 22:09:22.758  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] w.s.c.ServletWebServerApplicationContext : Root WebApplicationContext: initialization completed in 36700 ms
2022-03-03 22:09:39.465  WARN 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] ConfigServletWebServerApplicationContext : Exception encountered during context initialization - cancelling refresh attempt: org.springframework.beans.factory.UnsatisfiedDependen>
2022-03-03 22:09:40.059  INFO 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] ConditionEvaluationReportLoggingListener :

Error starting ApplicationContext. To display the conditions report re-run your application with 'debug' enabled.
2022-03-03 22:09:40.847 ERROR 34473 --- [io-8080-exec-51] o.s.b.d.LoggingFailureAnalysisReporter   :

***************************
APPLICATION FAILED TO START
***************************

Description:

Field brandDao in MMRR.contoroller.BrandController required a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' that could not be found.

The injection point has the following annotations:
        - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)


Action:

Consider defining a bean named 'entityManagerFactory' in your configuration.

03-Mar-2022 22:09:43.078 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-61] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.undeploy Undeploying context [/MM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT]
03-Mar-2022 22:11:19.006 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-63] org.apache.catalina.startup.HostConfig.deployWAR Deploying web application archive [/opt/tomcat/apache-tomcat-9.0.58/webapps/MM-0.0.1-SNAPSHOT.war]
03-Mar-2022 22:14:39.279 INFO [http-nio-8080-exec-63] org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner.scanJars At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were >
```

Comment: Try removing `<scope>provided</scope>` from your tomcat dependency

Comment: @ValerijDobler, thanks for you reponse,
I have tried to delete <scope>provided</scope> , but the error still exist.
I get the same error

Comment: what is "embedded server of eclipse"? eclipse does not have an embedded web server. are you referring to spring-boot embedded server